# Simplifying a min-max problem

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I have the following min-max problem
$$
\min_{t\geq 0_{K}} \max_{x_1\in \mathbb{R},x_2\in \mathbb{R}} [t'A+x_1t'B+x_2 t'C]
$$
where $t$ is a $K\times 1 $ vector, $0_K$ is $K\times 1$ vector of zeros, $A,B,C$ are  $K\times1$ vectors of known numbers.

I would like your help to understand if there is a way to simplify this problem. For example, is there a way to transform it into a unique minimisation problem?

Comment: What is $\geq$ for vectors? Each component is $\geq$ (in this case, non-negative)?

Comment: Yes, each element is non-negative. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is trivial I think. I assume $A,B,C$ are linearly independent. Let's write the solution in this form $t_*=aA+bB+cC+dD$, here $a,b,c,d$ are unknowns and also $D$ is a vector that is orthogonal to the basis $\{A,B,C\}$, in other words if we construct the matrix $M=[A\; B \;C]\in \mathbb{R}^{K\times3}$ then $D\in N(M)$ or $D$ is in the nullspace of $M$. Here for a general $t$ the problem

$$\max_{x_1\in \mathbb{R},x_2\in \mathbb{R}} [t_*^TA+x_1t_*^TB+x_2 t_*^TC]=\\\max_{x_1\in \mathbb{R},x_2\in \mathbb{R}} [\text{something}+x_1(b\Vert B\Vert_2^2+aA^TB+cC^TB)+x_2(aA^TC+bB^TC+c\Vert C\Vert_2^2) ]$$

which is unbounded above unless $\begin{cases}b\Vert B\Vert_2^2+aA^TB+cC^TB = 0\\aA^TC+bB^TC+c\Vert C\Vert_2^2=0\end{cases}$ we can extract $b,c$ as a function of $a$ from above equations

$$\begin{cases}b = \frac{\frac{A^TB}{\Vert B\Vert_2^2}-\frac{(A^TC)(C^TB)}{\Vert C\Vert_2^2\Vert B\Vert_2^2}}{1-\frac{(C^TB)(B^TC)}{\Vert B\Vert_2^2\Vert C\Vert_2^2}}a=m_1a\\c = \frac{\frac{A^TC}{\Vert C\Vert_2^2}-\frac{(A^TB)(B^TC)}{\Vert B\Vert_2^2\Vert C\Vert_2^2}}{1-\frac{(C^TB)(B^TC)}{\Vert B\Vert_2^2\Vert C\Vert_2^2}}a=m_2a\end{cases}$$

If these conditions being fulfilled, the outer optimization tier will be

$$\min_{t\geq 0_{K}} (a\Vert A \Vert^2+m_1aA^TB+m_2aA^TC)=\begin{cases}\min a &\text{if} \quad \Delta \ge 0 \\ \max a &\text{if} \quad \Delta < 0 \end{cases}$$

where $\Delta = \Vert A \Vert^2+m_1A^TB+m_2A^TC$. To solve the original problem. first we compute $m_1,m_2$ and then we compute $\Delta$. Then we solve the following feasibility problem

$$\text{find} \quad a\in\mathbb{R},n \in\mathbb{R}^K \\
\text{s.t.}\quad a(A+m_1B+m_2C)+n^T(I-M(M^TM)^{-1}M^T) \in\mathbb{R}_+^K$$

If this problem is feasible and has the solution $v$, since $\mathbb{R}_+^K$ is a convex cone then any $ev,e\in \mathbb{R}_+$ is also a solution. Thus if $\Delta\ge 0$, The optimum solution will zero. If $\Delta <0$ the problem will be unbounded below. If the feasibility problem is infeasible, then the original problem is unbounded above.

Comment: Thank you. This is useful but very hard to follow for me. Could you highlight your final claim? Am I understanding correctly that the optimum is zero or the problem is unbounded below/above?

Comment: Yes, I think the optimization is either zeros or unbounded from above or below, by any chance can you verify it with optimization packages like fmincon in MATLAB? That would be give us a nice insight.

Comment: Can I rewrite my problem as a unique quadratic min problem? I don't think so, right? The most I can do is writing it as  $\min_{t\geq 0_{4\times 1}} - \min_{x_1,x_2}- (t' A+x_1 t' B+x_2t'C)$.

Comment: Yes I think that's the best we could do, the epigraph form is out of reach since $x_1,x_2$ are continuous, the objective is linear so there is no quadratic chance, also I can't find any saddle point structure like the one we see in zero-sum games (the bi-linear structure).